# Insert code at the start and end of the outer nested code block only

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I have some code like:

```
void main() {
//----------
  var a;
  var b;
  var c =[];
  var c = func(3);
  if (a == b) {
    print "nested";
  }    
//----------------
}
```

I want to select the inner portion in between brackets, This is what i have tried:

`sed -re ':l;N;$!tl;N;s!(void \w+\(\) \{)([^])*!\1 Prepend;\n\2\nappend!g' test.txt`

**Edit:**

I am trying to insert code after the first occurrence `{` and before the last occurrence of `}`.

Example:

```
void main() { 
test1
//-----------------
  var a;
  var b;
  var c =[];
  var c = func(3);
  if (a == b) {
    print "nested";
  }
test2
//-----------------
}
```

Comment: Try `awk` and ignore the lines containing the braces.

Answer (score 3):

I think `awk` is a better solution for what you *actually* want to do:

```
$ awk '/{/{i++;if(i==1){print $0,"\ntest1";next}}{print}/}/{i--;if(i==1)print "test2"}' file
void main() { 
test1
//-----------------
  var a;
  var b;
  var c =[];
  var c = func(3);
  if (a == b) {
    print "nested";
  }
test2
//-----------------
}
```

Explanation:

Here is the script in multiline form with some explanatory comments, if you prefer it in this form save it to a file say `nestedcode` and run it like `awk -f nestedcode code.c`:

```
BEGIN{
    #Track the nesting level 
    nestlevel=0
}
/{/ {
    #The line contained a { so increase nestlevel
    nestlevel++
    #Only add code if the nestlevel is 1
    if(nestlevel==1){
        #Print the matching line and new code on the following line
        print $0,"\ntest1"
        #Skip to next line so the next block 
        #doesn't print current line twice
        next
    }
}
{
    #Print all lines
    print
}
/}/ {
    # The line contained a } so decrease the nestlevel
    nestlevel--
    #Only print the code if the nestleve is 1
    if(nestlevel==1)
        print"test2"
}
```

Comment: I have many functions like those in my file with mnay brackets, so i can't just use brackets as search thing

Comment: @user1953864 it would have been so much easier for everyone if you actually asked the question you want to solve and provide all the information from the start.

Comment: Actually i was nearly there and was not able to select anything between brackets. but sorry for that. i thought that was easy and didn't wanted to ask the whole thing. isn't that possible in sed. i am always confused when i ask for sed people say use awk and when i ask for awk , peoplesay use sed

Comment: @user1953864 always ask the full question and show what you have tried `sed` isn't a good tool for this problem.

Comment: @user1953864 - wrt sed vs awk: If you are doing a simple substitution on a single line, use sed. If you're doing anything else use awk. If you're using more than the "s" and "g" sed commands you are almost certainly using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^void.*{$/!b;:a;/\n}$/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;s/\n/&test1&/;s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\n\)/\1test2\n\2/' file
```

- `/^void.*{$/!b` if the line doesn't begin with `void` and end in `{` bail out (this may need to be tailored for your own needs).
- `:a;/\n}$/bb;$!{N;ba}` if the line contains a newline followed by a `}` only, branch to label `b` otherwise read in the next line and loop back to label `a`.
- `:b` begin substitutions here.
- `s/\n/&test1&/` after the first newline insert the first string.
- `s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\n\)/\1test2\n\2/` after the 2nd from last newline insert the second string.

Comment: i did understand you code. can you please explain character by character what each is doing. i am new to regex and sed , i didn't get that. othwise i have to ask new question to understand that

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
{[^]*} // [^] = any character, including newlines.
```

JavaScript example of the Regex working:

```
var s = "void main() {\n//----------\nvar a;\nvar b;\nvar c =[];\nvar c = func(3);\n//----------------\n}"
console.log(s.match(/{[^]*}/g));
//"{↵//----------↵var a;↵var b;↵var c =[];↵var c = func(3);↵//----------------↵}"
```

(I know this ain't JS question, but it works to illustrate that the regex returns the desired result.)

Comment: The question is tagged `sed`, which is not JavaScript.

Comment: @Amber: That doesn't mean JS can't be used to illustrate that a regex works.

Comment: When the regular expression engines operate in completely different ways, it's not a useful answer.

Comment: The engine might be different, but the Regex itself is standardised. I am sure the OP knows how to run regexes, I gave him the regex to use, and a example showing that the regex does what he wants.

Comment: @Cerbrus i have edited the question  and tried ur solution and it did worked

Comment: @Cerbus sorry buddy , i wanted to say did not worked and missed not there.

Answer (score -1):

`sed`, by default, operates on single lines. It can operate on multiple lines by using the `N` command to read more than one line into the pattern space.

For example, the following sed expression would join consecutive lines in a file with `@` symbols between them:

```
sed -e '{
N
s/\n/ @ /
}'
```

(Example from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-multi-line-file-operation-with-6-practical-examples/)

Comment: This might answer how to run multiline regexes, but this doesn't answer his actual question on how to match the piece of code between the brackets (`{}`).

Comment: i am using N and with multilines but i was not able to backreference that insode part between brackets. i need append and prepend something to it. can you give some example where i can prepend 'TEST1' and append 'TEST2' within brackets

Comment: @user1953864 if that's what you need to do, what I'd suggest doing instead is run two modifications - first, add `TEST1` after the line with a `{`, and then add `TEST2` before the line with a `}`.