# Need Assistance with understanding this regex in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210497/insert-code-at-the-start-and-end-of-the-outer-nested-code-block-only) and someone answered with this

`sed '/^void.*{$/!b;:a;/\n}$/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;s/\n/&test1&/;s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\n\)/\1test2\n\2/' file`

i am new to sed and regex and am not able to understand what is the function of each part.

i will try to explain what i have understood and you guys can fill the missing things. i will be going by character by character

1. `^void.*{$` -- This means anything that starts with `void` and ends with `{`
2. `/!b;` i didn't get what this does. Now `b` is for `branching`. what is `/` doing there
3. `:a;` is for making label `a`
4. `/\n` Again did not understood `/` there
5. `}$` that ends with `}`
6. `/bb` i don't get it
7. `$!` means if not end of file
8. `{N;` didn't get what it means , N means to copy next line in buffer but did get `{`
9. `:b` Didn't get it. b is for branching but don't know what its doing there
   10.`s/\n/&test1&/` i think its replacing \n with `\ntest1\n` but not sure
10. `s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\n\)/\1test2\n\2/` dont get this one as well

Comment: Looks like the person who answered your question added [an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14215634/1938444).

Comment: he added the expalantion in groups and i don't even understand that. i wanted to understand on character by character basis

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you should be using awk instead. I've been using sed for 30 years and couldn't even guess at what that command you posted is doing. If you find yourself using more than the "s" and "g" sed commands you're probably using the wrong tool so don't waste your time on this stuff, just get an awk solution and it'll be clearer, simpler and easier to enhance in future.

Comment: @Ed Morton , i was using awk previously but people keep saying use sed. Really i am not able to differentiate when to use what. i will post new question now (if thats not closed") so that can get idea when to use what

Comment: @user1953864 - the attraction of using sed for even moderately complicated problems is the same as the attraction of solving a puzzle. If you can figure out the correct arcane combination of punctuation marks and letters then you'll feel good about yourself and had a good mental workout but in the end you've done nothing productive. See my previous comment for concrete advice on when sed is the right tool to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain multiple sed expressions together with the `;` character.  Here's a look at each one separately.

The first expression, `/^void.*{$/!b`, has a matcher expression between the delimiting `/`'s.  It matches:

`^` - the beginning of the line

`void` - followed by the characters "void"

`.*` - followed by anything

`{` - followed by a left curly

`$` - followed by the end of the line

The modifier in that first expression, `!b`, means that if the matcher doesn't match, abort the sed evaluation.

The `:a` expression is a label.  It's used with a goto-like sed feature called branching.  We'll see how labels are used in the next expression.

The expression `/\n}$/bb` matches:

`\n` - a newline

`}` - followed by a right curly

`$` - followed by the end of the line

The modifier `bb` means that if you find a match, "branch" to the label b.  Label b is defined in a later expression as `:b`.

The `$!{N;ba}` expression should be read as one, even though it has a `;` in the middle.  The curlies in this case represent a series of commands that are meant to be executed together.

`$!` - if it's not the end of input

`{` - start group of commands (in this case, there are two of them)

`N` - read another line, silently

`ba` - branch to label a

`}` - end group of commands

Next is the label `:b`, which we'll hit when we match a single `}` on a line by itself, via the `/\n}$/bb` expression.

Lastly there are two substitute patterns, which are pretty standard regex.  The `s` before the expression essentially means `s/find_this/replace_it_with_this/`.  In the case of `s/\n/&test1&/`, we have:

`\n` - find a newline

`/` - and replace it with

`&` - the thing that was matched in the first expression (in this case, a newline)

`test1` - the word test1

`&` - and again the thing that was matched

So basically `s/\n/&test1&/` means replace the next `\n` with `\ntest1\n`.

The last expression is similar, but introduces something called captures.  Captures let you still match everything, but keep everything between `\(` and `\)` for use in the replace part of the expression.  For example `s/a\(b\)c\(d\)e/\1 \2/` would output `b d` if given an input string of `abcde`.  In the example, `\1` and `\2` are replaced with the things that are captured in escaped parens, `b` and `d`, respectively.

`s` - this is a substitution pattern:

`/` - find

`\(` - and put into the `\1` replacement variable

`.` - anything

`*` - and any amount of it

`\n` - including the first newline you come across

`\)` - (end of capture for `\1`)

`\(` - and put into the `\2` replacement variable

`.` - anything

`*` - and any amount of it

`\n` - including the first newline you come across

`\)` - (end of capture for `\2`)

`/` - and replace it all with

`\1` - the first thing captured,

`test2\n` - test2\n,

`\2` - and the second thing captured.

Answer (score 2):

This term:

```
/^void.*{$/!b
```

means match `^void.*{$` and the slashes are regex delimiters surrounding the regex. So you get `/^void.*{$/`. If an exclamation mark follows the match expression as in `/regex/!` then this means do the following command if regex does `not` match. The following command is `b` which is branch. Which, without a label name, branches at the end of the script. So in total this expression tries to match `^void.*{$` (i.e., line starting with void and ending with `{`) and jumps over (`b`) the rest of the script in case match fails (`!`).

This thing:

```
:a;/\n}$/bb;$!{N;ba};
```

starts a label `:a;` and tries to match `\n}$` (a newline and a single `}` on a line) which is again enclosed in `/regex/`. Upon a match it branches (`b`) to label b (hence, `/regex/bb`). If this is not the end of input ( `$!` ), then read a line `N` and jump back to the label a (`ba`). The curly pair here (i.e., `{commands}`) creates a block. This block 
is executed as a whole if `$!` is true, meaning there is more input. So `$!{N;ba}` simply means:

```
If not end of input:
begin
   real line
   jump to label a
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , i am now getting that